# Cypress.io::Integration folder supporting multiple folders in cypress.io,the created folder was not showing up in cypress:open test runner

Tags: cypress

Cypress.io::Integration folder supporting multiple folders in cypress.io,the created folder was not showing up in cypress:open test runner

tried all the ways like in cypress.json made the changes like:
"integrationFolder": "src/integrationTests/.",

my tests are in project root path<example/src/integrationTests/SanityTests>
i have added regressionTests folder in src<example/src/integrationTests/SanityTests>

but in test runner its only showing sanityTests only

below are configs in cypress.json:
"integrationFolder": "src/integrationTests/.",
"fixturesFolder": "src/integrationTests/.",

and testFiles i have not mentioned in cypress.json